# Can someone help me to understand different informatica lookup caches?

Tags: informatica

I have read theory with great detail but actually want to know the inside what actually happened with examples

Comment: Describe what you know - I'll help with the details. This way you'll learn more!

Answer (score 0):

Cache is a term related to temporal storage on program run so, if cache is on it speeds up the actual process. Therefore, a Lookup Cache can be used on lookup tables to look up the data  faster by storing in cache each time a program executes meaning once the mapping is run the lookup cache will store that result data of the lookup for that run and next time the data will be fetched from lookup cache not actual lookup tables.

Finally, If you want to have the cache created only on temporial basis or for long term storage then you can have different types of caches as Static and Dynamic Look up Cache.

Refer this for more https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://idwbi.com/types-of-lookup-caches-in-informatica/&ved=2ahUKEwjwytKdv-vjAhWVTX0KHQx8B7sQFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw3QViVccL_tK8g1Lp9D3rIE